# register namespace in silex without composer

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload, silex

I'm using silex to build an api for an app I'm building, and I want to abstract my controllers into different files.

I work for a pretty big corporation with a very strict IT department, and they won't let me install composer. For this reason, I need to register namespaces manually, via the `$loader->add()` function, but I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'App\Controller\SessionController' not found in C:\path\to\webroot\App\bootstrap.php on line 9
```

Does anyone know why the autoloader isn't picking up my App namespace?

Currently, my app is structured as follows:

```
App/
    Controller/
        ApiControllerAbstract.php
        SessionController.php
    bootstrap.php
vendor/
www/
    index.php
```

**index.php**

```
require_once "../app/bootstrap.php";
```

**bootstrap.php**

```
$loader = require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('App', __DIR__ . '/../App/');


$app = new Silex\Application();


$app->mount('/session', new App\Controller\SessionController());

$app->run();
```

**SessionController.php**

```
namespace App\Controller;

class SessionController extends ApiControllerAbstract {

    public function connect( $app)
    {
        $this->app = $app;
        $controller_collection = $app['controllers_factory'];

        // DECLARE ALL YOUR ROUTES HERE
        //...


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello,
The following line:

```php
$loader->add('App', __DIR__ . '/../App/');
```

Should be:

```php
$loader->add('App', __DIR__ . '/../');
```